# JS how often is value smaller then bevor in a array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, count

can someone help me by the following problem?

example array:

```
[2, 0, 5, 3, 1, 7, 8, 6, 4]
```

Now i need a counter how often is the number smaller than the numbers before. But dont counter the 0

in the example Array:

```
3 is smaller then 5
1 is smaller then 3,5,2 
6 is smaller then 8,7 
4 is smaller then 6,8,6,5

counter result = 10
```

solved:

```js
const oneArray = [2, 0, 5, 3, 1, 7, 8, 6, 4]

let countPairs = (oneArray) => {
  let counter = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < oneArray.length; i++) {
    for (let m = 0; m < i; m++) {
      if (oneArray[i] != 0 && oneArray[i] < oneArray[m]) {
        counter += 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return counter;
};

console.log(countPairs(oneArray))
```

Answer (score 2):

The only problem I see with your code as written is that you left out the "don't count the zero" rule. Check to make sure that `oneArray[i] != 0` before bothering to do the inner loop to see whether it's less than the earlier elements, and you should get the right answer.

Comment: you are right. I corrected the code in the first post :-)

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity of your algorithm is `O(n^2)`. If you would like to improve it to `O(n log n)`, consider how each step in a [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) can provide us with an opportunity to count out-of-order pairs as we swap or merge them.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine beside adding `oneArray[i]!=0` so that the counter won't be incremented if there is a 0 also it's better to start your loop from 1 for (let i = 1; i < oneArray.length; i++) first loop of `i` is unnecessary

```js
let countPairs = (oneArray) => {
  let counter = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i < oneArray.length; i++) {
    for (let m = 0; m < i; m++) {
      if (oneArray[i] < oneArray[m] &&oneArray[i]!=0) {
        counter += 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return counter;
};
console.log(countPairs([2, 0, 5, 3, 1, 7, 8, 6, 4]));
```